# What is the correct way to apply Structural Semantic Vocabulary over multiple content documents?

Tags: epub, chapters

I'm manually converting a book from HTML to ePub. The book is an anthology of works: a work of three volumes with each volume comprising several chapters.

I'd like to use the [Structural Semantic Vocabulary (SSV)](https://idpf.github.io/epub-vocabs/structure/) to describe the components—let's just say for arbitrary purposes for now. However, I also I intend to split the content into HTML files per-chapter with an additional title page per-volume:

```
volume-i-titlepage.xhtml
volume-i-chapter-i.xhtml
volume-i-chapter-ii.xhtml
volume-ii-titlepage.xhtml
volume-ii-chapter-i.xhtml
volume-ii-chapter-ii.xhtml
```

Thus I'm unsure where you would identify `epub:type="volume"` in a way that would mark all relevant content as being a child of that volume.

*Another example of this would be if you split a chapter over two content documents, I'm not sure where you would apply `epub:type="chapter"`.*

If it were a single content document, I suppose I'd use markup like so:

```
<section epub:type="volume">
  <header epub:type="titlepage"/>
  <section epub:type="chapter"/>
  <section epub:type="chapter"/>
</section>

<section epub:type="volume">
  <header epub:type="titlepage"/>
  <section epub:type="chapter"/>
  <section epub:type="chapter"/>
</section>
```

Looking at more strict '[edupub](http://idpf.org/epub/profiles/edu/spec/)' compliance, would on cursory reading suggest that such semantic blocks not be split between content documents.

A secondary concern is whether the implied root semantics here is compliant as would be a challenge for any anthology/compilation:

```
bodymatter
    frontmatter
    bodymatter
    bodymatter
/bodymatter

bodymatter
    frontmatter
    bodymatter
    bodymatter
/bodymatter
```

Comment: This [edupub sample](https://github.com/IDPF/education/tree/master/samples/structure-sample-01) perhaps reflects intended practice.

Comment: The section [content chunking](https://web.archive.org/web/20140601002912/http://epubzone.org/news/epub-3-content-documents#_content_chunking) in this article suggests the best option is to remove all children from parents where some children will appear in separate content documents.